# print nested list selecting specific items all in one line of code

Tags: python, printing, nested

I'm trying to print all the students that have "A" with one line of print code. What am I doing wrong?

```
students = [["Will", "B"], ["Kate", "B"], ["Max", "A"], 
["Elsa", "C"], ["Alex", "B"], ["Chris", "A"]]
print([dict(students)],(for v in [dict(students)]).items()=='A')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is python? You can just do:

```
[keys for keys,values in dict(students).items() if values == 'A']
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see my mistake. I think I tried something close to that, but I must have missed something because it didn't work.